# XML Eclipse Plugin. How to use the 'tab' key as a shortcut

Tags: xml, eclipse, plugins

I am currently developing an Eclipse XML editor plugin. I am currently struggling to implement a short cut feature. I want to be able to use the tab key in order to jump between the quotation marks in the below code snippet. By this I mean, type the query name, press 'tab' and then jump the the types quotation marks.

```
<query name="" type="" />
```

I'm confused to which extension in the plugin.xml I should use and also how to generally implement this. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your editor is derived from `TextEditor` there is already a handler for Tab with a defined action. You should be able to override this by overriding the `createActions` method:

```java
protected void createActions()
{
  super.createActions();

  IAction action = ..... your IAction to do the tabbing

  // Replace tab handler
  setAction(ITextEditorActionConstants.SHIFT_RIGHT_TAB, action);
}
```

Your `IAction` should extend `TextEditorAction`. This gives you access to the editor. The `run` method might be:

```java
public void run()
{
  ITextEditor ed = getTextEditor();
  if (!(ed instanceof AbstractTextEditor))
    return;

  if (!validateEditorInputState())
    return;

  AbstractTextEditor editor = (AbstractTextEditor)ed;
  ISourceViewer sv = editor.getSourceViewer();
  if (sv == null)
    return;

  IDocument document = sv.getDocument();
  if (document == null)
    return;

  StyledText st = sv.getTextWidget();
  if (st == null || st.isDisposed())
    return;

  int caret = st.getCaretOffset();

  // Offset in document of the caret

  int offset = AbstractTextEditor.widgetOffset2ModelOffset(sv, caret);

  int newOffset  = ... your code to change the position

  // Set caret from new document offset

  int widgetCaret = AbstractTextEditor.modelOffset2WidgetOffset(sv, newOffset);

  st.setSelectionRange(widgetCaret, 0);
```

(adapted in part from `InsertLineAction`).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am using TextEditor. How would I specifically create an action to jump between the quotation marks?